# Limit the number of pages created by the paging

Tags: pages, pagination, limit

Any way to limit the number of pages that are created automatically by paging? I would limit to five pages in all, authors, tags, categories ... Ex: "site.com/tag/news/page/5", "...author/admin/page/5."

Thanks.

Comment: In the backend?

Comment: Hi @Rutwick Gangurde In the frontend.

Comment: The paging can be controlled if you can edit the theme files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seem to work. Put in your `functions.php`:

```
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'limit_pages');
function limit_pages($query) {

    $query->max_num_pages = 5;
    if ($query->query_vars['paged'] > 5) {
        $query->query_vars['paged'] = 5;
        $query->query['paged'] = 5;
    }

    return $query;
}
```

But I guess you would still need some workaround for posts pagination and authors. Hope it helps you a little.

Comment: thanks for trying @Vinicius Massuchetto, but this function has not changed.

Comment: Well.. it is working here. Did you try accessing `page/6/`, `page/7/`, `page/8/`? They should all look the same.

Comment: Please note that this way all your posts are still directly accessible, we're just dealing with pagination here.

Comment: The comment is fine. Just leave it there. =D

Comment: Oh, sorry @Vinicius Massuchetto, now it is working. Now we need to adapt my function to display pagination links only to the number 5 (Pages: 1 2 3 4 5). Chosen to best response. Thanks!